# Why is this jQuery script isn't working in Chrome and Opera while it's perfectly fine in Firefox, IE and Safari?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, opera

I'm using the following script to select all checkboxes in a gridview through a checkbox in the header

```
$("[id*=chkboxSelectAll]").click(function ()
    {
        var chkboxSelectAll = $(this);
        var grid = "[id*=grdStudents]";
        $("input[type=checkbox]", grid).each(function ()
        {
            if (chkboxSelectAll.is(":checked"))
            {
                $(this).prop("checked", "checked");
            } else
            {
                $(this).removeProp("checked");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) says clearly:

> **Note:** Do not use this method to remove native properties such as
>   checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property
>   completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. **Use
>   .prop() to set these properties to false instead.**

As a word of caution, try to avoid removeProp() if you plan to never use the property again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the previous script is the following line:

```
$(this).removeProp("checked");
```

I substituted it with the following line:

```
$(this).prop("checked", "");
```

Then it worked just fine. **Any Idea why this is making a problem in some browser while not in others?**

Comment: I would suggest to add this to your question as this is your main question :)